# I want to pass a JS variable onto PHP and use it there

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to pass variables to PHP from JavaScript.  I've read about not being able to do this without a AJAX call, or putting it in the URL in JavaScript and then working with `$_GET`. The problem is that my variables are created on initialize (on window load) so if I try `$_GET` I get stuck in an infinite loop.

The variables are `lati` and `longi`.

Here is my JavaScript (without the AJAX call, since that created an infinite loop etc..):

```
var map;

 function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      streetViewControl: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);


     // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

  var lati = position.coords.latitude;
  var longi = position.coords.longitude;


       map.setCenter(pos);

    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }

  var length = locationsArray.length, element=null;
  for (var i = 0; i <length; i++)
  {
    element= locationsArray[i];

    var element1 = element.split(";");
    var posi = new google.maps.LatLng(element1[0],element1[1]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: posi,
    map: map,
    icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter_withshadow&chld='+i+'|e74c3c|333333',
    url: 'index.php?id='+i+'#eventDetails'
   });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    window.location.href = this.url;
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

The PHP where I want to use the variable:

```
$url="http://build.uitdatabank.be/api/events/search?key=AEBA59E1-F80E-4EE2-AE7E-CEDD6A589CA9&latlng=".$lati.";".$longi."!10km&format=json";
$events= json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
```

Comment: jQuery ajax is what you're looking for. What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried this:
   $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'index.php',
          data: {variable : lati, variable2: longi}
        });
        
and then getting them in my .php with  this:
$lati = $_POST['variable'];
 $longi = $_POST['variable2'];

I have no idea if this is the right way though, since I suck at ajax.

Answer (score 0):

just put a script tag in your `<head>` element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.lati = <?=json_encode($_GET["lati"]);?>;
window.longi= <?=json_encode($_GET["longi"]);?>;
</script>
```

now you can access it from everywhere within your Javascript in the page

Don't forget to validate the values before you print it directly to your output (to prevent [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack - even though the `json_encode` function may help to prevent some of it
(for example - if your parameters are coordinates, like it seems to be - check them for being numeric first with `is_numeric` function)

an example for validity check:

```
<?
$lng = null;
$lat = null;
if(isset($_GET["longi"]) && is_numeric($_GET["longi"])){
    $lng = $_GET["longi"];
}
if(isset($_GET["lat"]) && is_numeric($_GET["lat"])){
    $lat = $_GET["lat"];
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.lati = <?=json_encode($lat);?>;
window.longi= <?=json_encode($lng);?>;
</script>
```

Comment: When I try this, I get these errors:

Notice: Undefined index: variable in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectuit\projectuit\index.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: variable2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectuit\projectuit\index.php on line 7

Comment: so you're trying to access an undefined indexes in some array, 
a quick solution will be to wrap each access with `if(isset($ARRAY['variable1'])){}`. the best way is to check the variables (existence + validity) in the start of the page, and store the value in another var which will have a default value

Comment: @mykayyy check out the revision of my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't get any errors anymore now.
The problem now is, that my $url is already set with values "null" for both lat & long.

I guess the solution for this would be to refresh the page, but I don't know where to do that, since if I would do it after the window.longi part, I would get stuck in an infinite loop again.

Comment: I don't quiet understand what do you mean by "$url is already set"? are you sure you're trying to pass data from php the JS and not vice versa?

Comment: I'm trying to pass data from JS to PHP

Comment: @mykayyy read your question. you said "I want to pass variables to PHP from JavaScript", and this is what my answer was for..
If you're trying to do the opposite, AJAX will be the answer